# Blank Google Map on Android Device/Bluestack, But not when Debug

Tags: android, google-maps

My Google Map doesn't show up when installing on Android Device/Bluestack, but it is ok when debugging.

I installed using the apk produced with "Generate Signed APK" menu.

Error message (when using Bluestack): `E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. This might shine some light.

1. **Debug certificate**: The Android SDK tools generate this certificate automatically when you do a "debug" build from the command line, or when you build and run a project from Eclipse without exporting it as a released application. Only use this certificate with apps that you're testing; do not attempt to publish an app that's signed with a debug certificate.
2. **Release certificate**: The Android SDK tools generate this certificate when you do a "release" build with either ant program or Eclipse. You can also generate this certificate using the keytool program. Use this certificate when you are ready to release your app to the world.

Make sure you are using the right certificate.

Comment: Yes, I used release certificate which I produce using "Generate Signed APK" menu in Android Studio. I am considering to generate a new certificate, can you point me to the CORRECT command line. Can I use this one: `keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias android
debugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: well this how you generate debug key. For release key try this `keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name`

Comment: where do i get your_keystore_name or is this command to create one?

Comment: Thanks, i get it to works. i'm using debug sha1 to generate api key so only debug mode works. Now i'm using release sha1 to generate the api key.

Comment: No worries i did the same thing when i released my first Google maps application. Its a very minute thing which I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

If your api key is invalid or if you not enabled Google Maps Android API v2 in Google APIs Console in Services tab this exception might cause. Refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#create_an_api_project_in_the_google_apis_console) to enable that.

Comment: How come the api key is invalid when i debug it is ok. You need the right api key in order for the map to show up even in debug mode, right?

Comment: Have you switch on Google Maps Android API v2 in API console?

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I think it's something to do with my certificate generation. Can I use this to get the SHA1: `keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias android debugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: Thanks, i get it to works. i'm using debug sha1 to generate api key so only debug mode works. Now i'm using release sha1 to generate the api key.